# How can I efficiently tell if a batch of NPM packages has types?

Tags: npm, npm-registry

With the [NPM registry API](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md), I would like to determine whether a package has types. So far, I have this process, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to check:

- Query for `@types/<package>` (or download the `DefinitelyTyped` repository and check there, which is what I do for efficiency)
- Download the tarball for the package, unzip it, and check for `types` in `package.json`

I run this process for a few thousand packages.

However, I would like to make the latter check more efficient, given that the NPM website indicates whether a package has types.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this that doesn't require downloading tarballs?

Comment: I just realized that the `typings` field is exported when you query for `<package>`. However, since this doesn't work in bulk, I'll wait before I make it as an answer (as it isn't optimal, though it may be the only solution)